# Parse Incoming Email Subject Line in Sharepoint Designer 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library, designer-workflow, incoming-email

I'm quite new to Sharepoint and I'm having some difficulty in working with incoming emails.  I've modified an approval workflow to allow approvers to click "sendto" links to respond by email.  These emails are received in a document library.  I'm now trying to construct a workflow to read the subject line of these emails on arrival.  The problem I am having is that none of the available data fields in "Current Item" seem to reflect the email subject - or any of the other columns of the library item either!  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks,
CD

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the problem was that I was using a Globally Reusable workflow and I should have been using a List workflow.